# How to display animated SVG file in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, svg, svgkit

Is there a way to display an animated SVG file in iOS.

I am currently using SVGKit to display static SVG files, however I am interested in how to display animated SVGs such as the following file for example:

http://www.hypnobeast.com/spirals/Hypno_Beast_Spiral_1000x1000.svg

I am also aware of the following library: https://github.com/lukelutman/CCSVG, however I have been unable to compile it to see if it works.

The reason I ask is because our web developer has done all the work to create animated SVGs for our website, and I would rather not have to re-create the entire animation using CoreAnimation, which would take me forever to do.

Comment: If you explicitly state that you don't want to do it with Core Animation, maybe you shouldn't tag the question using Core Animation.

Comment: You may not need to re create the animations. Try the link in my answer and see if it works out for you.